# How to get contact number from contact_service Flutter

Tags: flutter, package

I'm useing contact_service to manage my contacts. I have fetch all contacts as a list. And I want to access fields with phone number of each contact.  I want to get it as a string but the atribute in Contact class is

```
Iterable<Item> phones
```

Do You know how can I get a phone number from this ?
Link to this package :
https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

For every `Iterable<Item> phones`, `Item.value` returns the phone number string.

```
List<String> names = [];
List<String> phones = [];

Iterable<Contact> _contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);

_contacts.forEach((contact) {
  contact.phones.toSet().forEach((phone) {
    names.add(contact.displayName ?? contact.givenName);
    phones.add(phone.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<Contact> _contacts;


     Future<void> refreshContacts() async {
        // Load without thumbnails initially.
        var contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts(
                withThumbnails: false, iOSLocalizedLabels: iOSLocalizedLabels))
            .toList();
        setState(() {
          _contacts = contacts;
        });
      }
```

and use this contact list  to render widget inside `ListView/Column`

Follow complete example here
https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/blob/master/example/lib/contacts_list_page.dart

Comment: Thanks for Your time but You missed my question. I have asked how to acces a phone number. I have allready fetch contact list. But I don't know how to acces phone mumber of each contact