# Radomly pick a number from contacts and call in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

When user click or touch the button, the application will randomly pick a number from user's phone contact list and call. I see this kind of app from google play store but I was wondering if it is possible to create one like this with flutter?

If yes, are there any resources I can look into?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

##### 1. How to get phone numbers?

You can look in [pub.dev, the official package repository for Dart and Flutter apps](https://pub.dev/). Search for ["get phone contact"](https://pub.dev/packages?q=get+phone+contact). Pick one package, then [use it to get the contact list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63546563/9157799).

##### 2. You got the list, how to randomly pick a number from the list?

[Google "dart get random element from list"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dart+get+random+element+from+list) and click [the first stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17476718/9157799) you see.

##### 3. You got the number, how to make the phone call?

[Repeat step number 1](https://pub.dev/packages?q=make+phone+call).